# MongoDB C# .Net Drivers version 2.0 location based queries

Tags: c#, mongodb, geolocation, mongodb-query

this works in 1.9

```
database.GetCollection<Places>("Places");
double maxDistanceInRadians = maxDistanceInMiles / 3959.0; 
var queryplaces = Query.WithinCircle("Loc", lon, lat, maxDistanceInRadians);
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursor cursor = places.Find(queryplaces).SetLimit(limit);
```

How to do a location query with 2.0, Query(MongoDb.Drivers.Builder.Query) does not seem to be part of 2.0 here's the [doc's](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/R_Project_CSharpDriverDocs.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this page : http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/upgrading/

On the section **Builders** says that all The old builders (Query, Update, etc…) have all been replaced by Builders.

The builder you want is now Builders.Filter.GeoWithinPolygon

Comment: brilliant, had discovered and was waiting for someone to provide the answer, well done

Comment: Mark as an answer please.